# Why I get "TypeError: getData is not a function", however it's a function of componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Here is my code:

> import React, { Component } from 'react';
>
> ```
> import './item-list.css';
> // import SwapiService from '../../services/swapi';
> import Spinner from "../spinner/spinner";
>
> export default class ItemList extends Component {
>
>   state = {
>     itemList: null
>   };
>
>   componentDidMount() {
>
>     const { getData } = this.props;
>
>     getData()
>       .then((itemList) => {
>         this.setState({
>           itemList
>         });
>       });
>   }
>
>   renderItems(arr) {
>     return arr.map((item) => {
>       const { id } = item;
>       const label = this.props.children(item);
>
>       return (
>         <li className="list-group-item"
>             key={id}
>             onClick={() => this.props.onItemSelected(id)}>
>           {label}
>         </li>
>       );
>     });
>   }
>
>   render() {
>
>     const { itemList } = this.state;
>
>     if (!itemList) {
>       return <Spinner />;
>     }
>
>     const items = this.renderItems(itemList);
>
>     return (
>       <ul className="item-list list-group">
>         {items}
>       </ul>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

**ERROR:
TypeError: getData is not a function
ItemList.componentDidMount**

I don't understand why I am getting this error in my project at getData(). I have not any idea how to solve this error.

Comment: Could you also add code where exactly you are using this component `ItemList`  ?

Comment: please provider more code about ItemList parent component

Comment: const itemList = (
        <ItemList>
        onItemSelected={this.onPersonSelected}
        getData={this.swapiService.getAllPeople}

        {(i) => (
          `${i.name} (${i.birthYear})`
        )}
        </ItemList>
      )

Comment: If you are gonna change the ```getData``` function in the ItemList component anyway then what is the purpose of passing it as a prop

Comment: What is `this.swapiService.getAllPeople`?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is using that component isn't passing a function into the prop `getData`.